# Proof of complex Bolzano–Weierstrass Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

Here is the proof from my lecture notes:

> Write $z_n = x_n + i y_n$. Let $M$ be such that $|z_n| \leq M$ for all $n$. Then by the definition of modulus in $\mathbb{C}$, we have $|x_n| \leq M$ and $|y_n| \leq M$, for all $n$. Therefore by the real BW Theorem, $(x_n)$ has a convergent subsequence, say $(x_{n_r} )$. Let $w_r := y_{n_r}$ , for $r \in \mathbb{N}$. Then
>   the subsequence $(w_r)$, being a subsequence of the bounded sequence $(y_n)$, is itself bounded. Choose a subsequence $(w_{r_s} )$ of $(w_r)$ which is convergent. Then $(y_{{n_{r_s}}} )$ converges and so does $(x_{{n_{r_s}}} )$, since it is a subsequence of a convergent sequence. Finally, $(z_{{n_{r_s}}} )$ is convergent since the sequences of real and imaginary parts converge.

What I don't understand is why we have to take a subsequence of $(w_r)$ when we could just specify that when we find $(w_r)$, we are finding a monotonic subsequence of $(y_n)$ which exists due to the Monotonic Subsequences Theorem.Then we know $(w_r)$ is bounded as $(y_n)$ is bounded and so that $(w_r)$ converges as it is both monotonic and bounded. Apply this same logic to $(x_n)$, and then we have that $(z_n)$ has a convergent subsequence.

Is there something wrong with my logic?

Thank you.

Comment: You need to insure that the $n$'th term of the two (sub)sequences correspond to the same $z_m$.

Comment: @DavidMitra Thank you, but why does this matter?

Comment: You want a convergent subsequence of $(z_n)$. If you find convergent subsequences $(b_n)$ and $(c_n)$ respectively of $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ haphazardly, there's nothing to guarantee that $b_n+i c_n$ is actually one of the $z_n$.  Perhaps I misunderstood what you were saying...

Comment: Ahh no, thank you. I just didn't understand the proof of $z_n$ being convergent depending on $x_n$ and $y_n$.