# Convergence of complex sequence with gradient descent

Tags: complex-analysis, optimization, cauchy-sequences, numerical-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

I am looking to solve the following otimization:

$\underset{{{{\bf x} \in \mathcal{X}}}}{\text{min}} \; f({\bf x})$

where ${\bf x} \in \mathbb{C}^N$ and $f({\bf x}) \in \mathbb{R}$, $f(x)$ is a convex function and $\mathcal{X}$ is a compact set but not convex.

I am solving the optimization using gradient descent where the iteration consists of the following step:

${\bf x}^{(t)} = proj_{\mathcal{X}}\left({\bf x}^{(t-1)} - \alpha \nabla f({\bf x}^{(t-1)})\right)$,

where $\alpha$ is the step size, $\nabla f({\bf x})$ is the graident and $proj_{\mathcal{X}}(.)$ projects a point on to the set $\mathcal{X}$.

Now suppose I prove that every subsequence ${\bf x}^{t_i}$ of the solution sequence ${\bf x}^{(t)}$ with a limit point $\bar{\bf x}^{*}$, i.e, ${\bf x}^{t_i} \to_{i \to \infty} \bar{\bf x}^{*}$ conerge to a KKT point of the above optimization problem, then based on fact that $\mathcal{\bf X}$ is a compact set and using the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem ([Proof of complex Bolzano–Weierstrass Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1067849/proof-of-complex-bolzano-weierstrass-theorem)), can I claim that the whole solution sequence converge to a KKT point of the original problem?

Comment: I'm sure it can be shown easily by contradiction. Just think what it actually means if this is not true.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Do you mean something like: If the whole solution sequence does not converge to a KKT point, this means that there exists a subsequence which does not converge to a KKT point.  As we can prove that all the subsequences converge to a KKT point, this creates a contradiction and hence the whole sequence always converge to a KKT point.  Can we derive this contradiction directly from the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem.

Comment: Yes, assume that the sequence does not converge. Then there is a subsequence that stays away from the limit. This subsequence is a sequence in a compact set, so there are convergent subsequences. This gives a contradiction.